# Calculating and storing pixelated ellipse

Tags: matrix, graphics, render, ellipse

I was wondering if it is possible to create a function (arbitrary of language) that has as input a width and height.

This function would then calculate the biggest ellipse that would fit inside of the dimensions that it is given, and store this in a matrix such as these two examples;

[image]
[image]

In the left example, the width is 14 and height is 27, where the white part is the ellipse.

In the right example, the width is 38 and height is 21, where, once again, the white part is the ellipse.

Of course, the black and white parts can be seen as true/false values if they are part of the ellipse or not.

Comment: Are you looking for an ellipse drawing algorithm such as [**this**](https://dai.fmph.uniba.sk/upload/0/01/Ellipse.pdf)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. The process is called ellipse rasterization. Here few methods to do so:

let our image has `xs,ys` resolution so center `(x0,y0)` and semiaxises `a,b` are:

```
x0=xs/2
y0=y2/2
a =x0-1
b =y0-1
```

1. **using ellipse equation**

   so 2 nested `for` loops + `if` condition deciding if you are inside or outside ellipse.

   ```cpp
   for (y=0;y<ys;y++)
    for (x=0;x<xs;x++)
     if (((x-x0)*(x-x0)/(a*a))+((y-y0)*(y-y0)/(b*b))<=1.0) pixel[y][x]=color_inside;
      else pixel[y][x]=color_outside;
   ```

   You can optimize this quite a lot by pre-computing the parts of the equations only if thy change so some are computed just once others on each `x` iteration and the rest on each `y` iteration. Also is better to multiply instead of dividing.
2. **using parametric ellipse equation**

   ```cpp
   x(t) = x0 + a*cos(t)
   y(t) = y0 + b*sin(t)
   t = <0,2.0*M_PI>  // for whole ellipse
   ```

   so one `for` loop creating quadrant coordinates and filling lines inside and outside for the 3 mirrors of the quadrant using only horizontal or only vertical lines. However this approach need a buffer to store the circumference points of one quadrant.
3. **Using Bresenham ellipse algorithm**
4. **Using any Circle algorithm and stretch to ellipse**

   so simply use square area of size of the lesser resolution from `xs,ys` render circle and than stretch back to `xs,ys`. If you do not stretch during rasterization than you might create artifacts. In such case is better to use the bigger resolution and stretch down but that is slower of coarse.

Comment: What you do in the first method is not called "rasterization". It only has to do with "**pixel-by-pixel rendering**" since the two loops iterate through every pixel in the matrix, checking if the pixel is inside or outside the ellipse. See "Two Approaches" section in [this webpage](https://academickids.com/encyclopedia/index.php/Rendering_%28computer_graphics%29) for more info.

Comment: @JavadBayat any rendering to raster image (uniform array of pixels/voxels/...) is called rasterization

Answer (score 1):

Drawing an ellipse and storing it in a matrix can be accomplished with two different methods: either **Rasterization** (the recommended way) or **pixel-by-pixel rendering**. According to @Spektre's comment, I wonder if both methods are called "rasterization" since they both render the ellipse to raster image. Anyway, I'll explain how to use both methods in C++ to draw an ellipse and store it in your matrix.

**Note:** Here I'll assume that the origin of your matrix `matrix[0][0]` refers to the upper-left corner of the image. So points on the matrix are described by x- and y-coordinate pairs, such that x-coordinates increase to the right; y-coordinates increase from top to bottom.

## Pixel-by-pixel ellipse rendering

With this method, you loop over all the pixels in your matrix to determine whether each pixel is inside or outside of the ellipse. If the pixel is inside, you make it white, otherwise, you make it black.

In the following example code, the `isPointOnEllipse` function determines the status of a point relative to the ellipse. It takes the coordinates of the point, coordinates of the center of the ellipse, and the lengths of semi-major and semi-minor axes as parameters. It then returns either one of the values `PS_OUTSIDE`, `PS_ONPERIM`, or `PS_INSIDE`, which indicate that the point lies outside of the ellipse, the point lies exactly on the ellipse's perimeter, or the point lies inside of the ellipse, respectively.

Obviously, if the point status is `PS_ONPERIM`, then the point is also part of the ellipse and must be made white; because the ellipse's outline must be colored in addition to its inner area.

**You must call `ellipseInMatrixPBP` function to draw an ellipse, passing it a pointer to your matrix, and the width and height of your matrix.** This function loops through every pixel in your matrix, and then calls `isPointOnEllipse` for every pixel to see if it is inside or outside of the ellipse. Finally, it modifies the pixel accordingly.

```
#include <math.h>

// Indicates the point lies outside of the ellipse.
#define PS_OUTSIDE  (0)
// Indicates the point lies exactly on the perimeter of the ellipse.
#define PS_ONPERIM  (1)
// Indicates the point lies inside of the ellipse.
#define PS_INSIDE   (2)

short isPointOnEllipse(int cx, int cy, int rx, int ry, int x, int y)
{
    double m = (x - cx) * ((double) ry) / ((double) rx);
    double n = y - cy;
    double h = sqrt(m * m + n * n);

    if (h == ry)
        return PS_ONPERIM;
    else if (h < ry)
        return PS_INSIDE;
    else
        return PS_OUTSIDE;
}

void ellipseInMatrixPBP(bool **matrix, int width, int height)
{
    // So the ellipse shall be stretched to the whole matrix
    // with a one-pixel margin.
    int cx = width / 2;
    int cy = height / 2;
    int rx = cx - 1;
    int ry = cy - 1;

    int x, y;
    short pointStatus;
    // Loop through all the pixels in the matrix.
    for (x = 0;x < width;x++)
    {
        for (y = 0;y < height;y++)
        {
            pointStatus = isPointOnEllipse(cx, cy, rx, ry, x, y);
            // If the current pixel is outside of the ellipse,
            // make it black (false).
            // Else if the pixel is inside of the ellipse or on its perimeter,
            // make it white (true).
            if (pointStatus == PS_OUTSIDE)
                matrix[x][y] = false;
            else
                matrix[x][y] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

## Ellipse rasterization

If the pixel-by-pixel approach to rendering is too slow, then use the rasterization method. Here you determine which pixels in the matrix the ellipse affects, and then you modify those pixels (e.g. you turn them white). Unlike pixel-by-pixel rendering, rasterization does not have to pass through the pixels that are outside of the ellipse shape, which is why this approach is so faster.

To rasterize the ellipse, it is recommended that you use the so-called [Mid-point Ellipse algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/midpoint-ellipse-drawing-algorithm/), which is an extended form of Bresenham's circle algorithm.

However, I've discovered an ellipse-drawing algorithm which is probably *sophisticated enough* (except for its performance) to compete with Bresenham's! So I'll post the function that you want - written in C++.

The following code defines a function named `ellipseInMatrix` that draws an ellipse with a one-pixel stroke, but does not fill that ellipse. You need to pass this function a pointer to the matrix that you have already allocated and **initialized to `false` values**, plus the dimensions of the matrix as integers. Note that `ellipseInMatrix` internally calls the `rasterizeEllipse` function which performs the main rasterizing operation. Whenever this function finds a point of the ellipse, it sets the corresponding pixel in the matrix to `true`, which causes the pixel to turn white.

```
#define pi (2 * acos(0.0))
#define coord_nil (-1)

struct point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

double getEllipsePerimeter(int rx, int ry)
{
    return pi * sqrt(2 * (rx * rx + ry * ry));
}

void getPointOnEllipse(int cx, int cy, int rx, int ry, double d, struct point *pp)
{
    double theta = d * sqrt(2.0 / (rx * rx + ry * ry));
    // double theta = 2 * pi * d / getEllipsePerimeter(rx, ry);

    pp->x = (int) floor(cx + cos(theta) * rx);
    pp->y = (int) floor(cy - sin(theta) * ry);
}

void rasterizeEllipse(bool **matrix, int cx, int cy, int rx, int ry)
{
    struct point currentPoint, midPoint;
    struct point previousPoint = {coord_nil, coord_nil};
    double perimeter = floor(getEllipsePerimeter(rx, ry));
    double i;
    
    // Loop over the perimeter of the ellipse to determine all points on the ellipse path.
    for (i = 0.0;i < perimeter;i++)
    {
        // Find the current point and determine its coordinates.
        getPointOnEllipse(cx, cy, rx, ry, i, &currentPoint);
        // So color the current point.
        matrix[currentPoint.x][currentPoint.y] = true;

        // So check if the previous point exists. Please note that if the current
        // point is the first point (i = 0), then there will be no previous point.
        if (previousPoint.x != coord_nil)
        {
            // Now check if there is a gap between the current point and the previous
            // point. We know it's not OK to have gaps along the ellipse path!
            if (!((currentPoint.x - 1 <= previousPoint.x) && (previousPoint.x <= currentPoint.x + 1) && 
            (currentPoint.y - 1 <= previousPoint.y) && (previousPoint.y <= currentPoint.y + 1)))
            {
                // Find the missing point by defining its offset as a fraction
                // between the current point offset and the previous point offset.
                getPointOnEllipse(cx, cy, rx, ry, i - 0.5, &midPoint);
                matrix[midPoint.x][midPoint.y] = true;
            }
        }

        previousPoint.x = currentPoint.x;
        previousPoint.y = currentPoint.y;
    }
}

void ellipseInMatrix(bool **matrix, int width, int height)
{
    // So the ellipse shall be stretched to the whole matrix
    // with a one-pixel margin.
    int cx = width / 2;
    int cy = height / 2;
    int rx = cx - 1;
    int ry = cy - 1;

    // Call the general-purpose ellipse rasterizing function.
    rasterizeEllipse(matrix, cx, cy, rx, ry);
}
```

If you need to fill the ellipse with white pixels like the examples that you provided, you can use the following code instead to rasterize a filled ellipse. Call the `filledEllipseInMatrix` function with a similar syntax to the previous function.

```
#define pi (2 * acos(0.0))
#define coord_nil (-1)

struct point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

double getEllipsePerimeter(int rx, int ry)
{
    return pi * sqrt(2 * (rx * rx + ry * ry));
}

void getPointOnEllipse(int cx, int cy, int rx, int ry, double d, struct point *pp)
{
    double theta = d * sqrt(2.0 / (rx * rx + ry * ry));
    // double theta = 2 * pi * d / getEllipsePerimeter(rx, ry);

    pp->x = (int) floor(cx + cos(theta) * rx);
    pp->y = (int) floor(cy - sin(theta) * ry);
}

void fillBar(struct point seed, bool **matrix, int cx)
{
    int bx;
    if (seed.x > cx)
    {
        for (bx = seed.x;bx >= cx;bx--)
            matrix[bx][seed.y] = true;
    }
    else
    {
        for (bx = seed.x;bx <= cx;bx++)
            matrix[bx][seed.y] = true;
    }
}

void rasterizeFilledEllipse(bool **matrix, int cx, int cy, int rx, int ry)
{
    struct point currentPoint, midPoint;
    struct point previousPoint = {coord_nil, coord_nil};
    double perimeter = floor(getEllipsePerimeter(rx, ry));
    double i;
    
    // Loop over the perimeter of the ellipse to determine all points on the ellipse path.
    for (i = 0.0;i < perimeter;i++)
    {
        // Find the current point and determine its coordinates.
        getPointOnEllipse(cx, cy, rx, ry, i, &currentPoint);
        // So fill the bar (horizontal line) that leads from
        // the current point to the minor axis.
        fillBar(currentPoint, matrix, cx);

        // So check if the previous point exists. Please note that if the current
        // point is the first point (i = 0), then there will be no previous point.
        if (previousPoint.x != coord_nil)
        {
            // Now check if there is a gap between the current point and the previous
            // point. We know it's not OK to have gaps along the ellipse path!
            if (!((currentPoint.x - 1 <= previousPoint.x) && (previousPoint.x <= currentPoint.x + 1) && 
            (currentPoint.y - 1 <= previousPoint.y) && (previousPoint.y <= currentPoint.y + 1)))
            {
                // Find the missing point by defining its offset as a fraction
                // between the current point offset and the previous point offset.
                getPointOnEllipse(cx, cy, rx, ry, i - 0.5, &midPoint);
                fillBar(midPoint, matrix, cx);
            }
        }

        previousPoint.x = currentPoint.x;
        previousPoint.y = currentPoint.y;
    }
}

void filledEllipseInMatrix(bool **matrix, int width, int height)
{
    // So the ellipse shall be stretched to the whole matrix
    // with a one-pixel margin.
    int cx = width / 2;
    int cy = height / 2;
    int rx = cx - 1;
    int ry = cy - 1;

    // Call the general-purpose ellipse rasterizing function.
    rasterizeFilledEllipse(matrix, cx, cy, rx, ry);
}
```